# php explode to split and combine reverse string

Tags: php

```
text left - text right
```

How to swap right to left using php? str pos is not so good because the pattern is not always fix. It could be `somethingleft-somethingright` or `more left text here - right`

The result that I want should look like `text right - text left`

tried explode() but it isn't always single character at the left or right side.

Comment: Instead of considering delimiter as "-", you can consider the delimiter as " - " (notice the spaces).

Comment: @Krumia sometime it's with space but sometime is has no space..

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @user3791372 explode() but there isn't only single char at left or right

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried

Comment: What do you mean by 'single character'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply can use `explode()`. Example here

```
$str = "text left - text right";
$exp = explode('-', $str);
$newStr = trim($exp[1]) . ' - ' . trim($exp[0]);
echo $newStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo trim( implode(' - ', array_reverse(explode('-', 'text left - text right'))));
```

Comment: It's a messy one liner but great for ability to use multiple delimiters

Answer (score 0):

```
$strArr = preg_split(' - ','text left - text right');
$newStr = $strArr[1] . ' - ' . $strArr[0];
```

Split the string using the pattern ' - '.  Then concatenate a new string by placing the right value `$strArr[0]` at the beginning of the concatenated string followed by the ' - ' pattern and finally the first half of the string `$strArr[0]`.

Comment: A simple explode will suffice, but until he pastes code, I'm not going to spoon feed him

Comment: explode() might not see the spaces